# ¿Cómo incluir mysql.h utilizando C compilando con mingw?

Tags: mysql, c, windows, vscode

Estoy intentando compilar un sencillo código para obtener la versión de MySQL instalada:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());
  
  exit(0);
}
```

Y el error es : `mysql/udf_registration_types.h: No such file or directory`

Estoy utilizando **vs code**, **mingw** y **mysql  Ver 8.0.26** en Windows.

Entiendo, por lo que estuve investigando que `mysql.h` no se encuentra en los "includes" de mingw.
He intentado buscar en la carpeta donde tengo instalado MySQL: `C:\Program Files\MySQL` el header necesario. Lo encontré en `\MySQL Server 8.0\include`. Entonces lo que hice fue agregarlo en el include del programa..

quedando:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());
  
  exit(0);
}
```

La compilación de este programa me trae ahora este error:

```
 C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgCx1kY.o: In function `main':
 C:/Users/Lucas/Documents/cpp/sql_connector/version.c:9: undefined
 reference to `mysql_get_client_info@0' collect2.exe: error: ld
 returned 1 exit status
```

vscode me sugiere actualizar el valor de `includePath`.
En el archivo de `c_cpp_propierties.json`, lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: No lo tienes que incluir asi: `#include <C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\mysql.h>`. Tienes que hacerlo asi: `#include <mysql.h>` y añadir `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include` a tu include path. Con Mingw lo haces con el flag `-I`. El error que te sale es porque no estas linkeando las librerias correspondientes. Para MySQL no se cuales seran, asi que te tocara buscar en internet.